# unable uninstall AMD Catalyst

Tags: kali-linux, amd-graphics, fglrx

I try perform `aticonfig --uninstall`, but yell like so :

```
*** AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Uninstall Log 2016-03-06 12:42:33 ***
File is missing from system /usr/bin/clinfo.
One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed.

To force uninstall, removing all installed files without verification,
run /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh --force.

Forcing uninstall is not recommended and may cause system corruption.
```

My goal just install newer version, because current version broke after **upgrade kernel** . I use Kali `2.0` with following kernel

```
4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [debian forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=71179#p397753).

1. Reinstall mesa and xorg

   ```
   apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
   ```
2. Reboot or restart

   ```
   reboot
   ```
3. Perform with --force option

   ```
   sh /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh --force
   ```